# Getting ProjectBOs from CatalogCategoryBO returns different results based on BusinessObjectRepositoryContext

Tags: intershop

We are trying to get all ProductBOs from CatalogCategoryBO with following code:

```
final CatalogBORepository catalogBORepository = applicationBO.getRepository("CatalogBORepository");
final CatalogCategoryBO catalogCategoryBO = catalogBORepository.getCatalogBOByCatalogName(catalogName).getCatalogCategoryBOByName(catalogCategoryName);
final CatalogCategoryBOCommonProductAssignmentExtension assignmentExtension = catalogCategoryBO.getExtension(CatalogCategoryBOCommonProductAssignmentExtension.class);
return assignmentExtension.getSortedProducts(applicationBO.getDefaultLocale());
```

But this does not always work as expected. After debugging I found out that main reason is BusinessObjectRepositoryContext:

```
((BusinessObjectRepositoryContext)catalogCategoryBO.getContext().getVariable("CurrentBusinessObjectRepositoryContext");
```

which is different based on location from which we call given method (organization or channel).

The same problem is described here: https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/IS-22604

Is there some workaround or better way to get all assigned ProductBOs from CatalogCategoryBO?

We are using Intershop B2C version 7.9.1.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to call pipeline for getting products as suggested by Willem Evertse, another one is to fetch CatalogBORepository and CatalogCategoryBO within block of:

```
try (ApplicationContext applicationContext = application.forceApplicationContext()) {
    // your code here
}
```

https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/2X3516#Concept-ApplicationFramework-TheExecutionContextofanApplication

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is because the business objects can have different implementations depending on the context (application).

If you look at how the rest api does it (see `ProductListResource`) they call the `ProductHandler` (see `ProductHandlerImpl`) method:
`getProducts(Domain currentChannel, CatalogCategoryBO category, String searchTerm, String localeId,...)`

Only the category parameter is mandatory it seems, the other parameters can be null. The added benefit is that this code will call the Solr index (if u have it enabled) so it should perform better than running a query on the database (which is also a possibility).

Comment: Yes, I can see how is done here. I managed to use code from my question within this block as sepcified here https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/2X3516#Concept-ApplicationFramework-TheExecutionContextofanApplication:

try (ApplicationContext applicationContext = application.forceApplicationContext())

Comment: Good solution too. You dont have to change the code